# Setting dynamic scope variables in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

This my frist time with AngularJs.I have problem about setting expression in `ng-style`
I try to set expression in `ng-style` by `item.variable_name`

```
    <div class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="item in MenuModel"
         ng-style="item.variable_name"
         ng-mouseover="onMouseOver(item.color,item.variable_name)" >
        <div class="col-md-12 sub-menu" ng-click="clickmenu(item.id)" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 menu-icon" style="background-color:{{item.color}};" >
                    <img class="img-icon" src="~/Resources/{{item.icon}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9" style="display:inline-block">
                    <h3 style="color:{{item.color}};">{{item.menu_name_th}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add style in Anglar.js like this

```
$scope.onMouseOver = function (color, variable_name) {

   $scope.variable_name = {
      'box-shadow': "0 4px 8px 0 " + color + ", 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) "
   };

}
```

I think setting method `$scope.variable_name` is the wrong way
Have you have a suggestion for me?
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)?

Comment: I want to use Angular so much that I can learn.Thank you for trying to help me ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `item.variable_name`, not `$scope.variable_name`. Pass the item into the function and then change the `variable_name`:

```
$scope.onMouseOver = function (item) {
    item.variable_name = { 'box-shadow': "0 4px 8px 0 " + item.color + ", 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) " };
}
```

```
ng-mouseover="onMouseOver(item)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I got the rigth value but the shadow color not change

Comment: Check that demo it works: [demo](https://codepen.io/billp212121/pen/GRgbwjv)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I changed `ng-style` to `ng-style="{'box-shadow': item.variable_name}"` and it work!